# When Copying a Folder from main drive to a shared drive I am loosing files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

When Trying to copy a template folder to a Shared drive using app scripts, all files and subfolders move to the new folder destination except the google sheet and google doc within the template folder. This same thing happens if you try to download the template folder and upload to the shared drive.

I even logged the file name of all of the files when it was copying the template folder and the google sheet and google doc where not recognized as files.

How can I get the google sheet and google doc to be recognized and moved to my new folder in the shared drive using apps scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You could zip the file before moving and unzip after.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer